# Swift/iOs/Sockets : How to receive sockets "events free" data?

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, sockets, websocket

I'm struggling to build a simple basic real chat app using apple's swift for client-side part and nodejs for the server-side.

i use a websockets library to manage client/server communication.

What i noticed in swift, it seems i can't catch data coming from my server without start an event. I'm trying to make my app supporting a bi-directional chatting between, in one hand sending/receiving messages from my IOS Simulator in xcode 7, and the other, do the same thing in my desktop web browser (firefox).

all messages created from both part are successfully registered in my mongodb database (via nodejs mongoose) but in iOs simulator when i designed a chat UI i need to restart the simulator each time i want to see new incoming messages.

**My goal is : Displaying all incoming messages from both firefox and iOS simulator in real time in my iOs simulator UI, using sockets of course. When i send a message from my browser to my iOs app , this one should be instantly displayed. It is the case when i send from the iOs Ui but not the same story when messages coming from firefox.**

Please, i would need some help in order to understand what is wrong with my code (In three parts) :

Xcode/Swift :

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ViewTwo: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate{

    var lab : [String!] = [];
    var desc : [String!] = [];
    var dictionnary : [String:String!] = ["user": nil,"message" : nil];
    var voidDict:[String:String!] = ["content" : "whatever"];

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var txtField: UITextField!
    @IBAction func addMessage(sender: AnyObject) {

        self.lab.insert("Hello", atIndex: 0);
        self.desc.insert(txtField.text!, atIndex: 0);
        dictionnary["user"] = "hello";
        dictionnary["message"] = txtField.text;
        SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.emit("saveChat", value: dictionnary);




    }




    override func viewDidLoad() {


        super.viewDidLoad()



        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80.0;
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
        SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.emit("ready", value: voidDict);


        SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.socket.on("chat"){data, ack in
            SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.socket.removeAllHandlers();

            for var i = 0; i < data[0].count; ++i{
                let usr = data[0][i]["user"] as! String;
                let mess = data[0][i]["message"] as! String;
                self.lab.insert(usr, atIndex: 0);
                self.desc.insert(mess, atIndex: 0);
            }

            self.tableView.reloadData();
        }


        socket.on("update"){data, ack in
     self.socket.removeAllHandlers();



    }



    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return desc.count;
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell;
        cell.hello.text = self.lab[indexPath.row];
        cell.descr.text = self.desc[indexPath.row];

        return cell;

    }



    }
```

Server side (nodejs)

```nodejs
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log("un utilisateur s'est connecté");


    socket.on("ready",function(err,data){
        Chat.find({},function(err,data){
            if(err) throw err;
            socket.emit("chat",data);

        })
    })
    socket.on('login',function(data){

        User.find({username:data.id,password:data.password},function(err,data){
            if(err) throw err;

            if(data.length > 0){
                socket.emit("message","true");
            }else{
                socket.emit("userNotFound","Sorry this user doesn't exists");
            }

        })


    })
    socket.on('saveChat',function(data){
        Chat.create({user:data.user,message:data.message},function(err){
            if(err) throw err;
            Chat.find({},function(err,data){
            if(err) throw err;
            socket.emit("chat",data);

        })


        });

    });

    socket.on('data',function(data){
        var entry = new Chat(data);
        entry.save(function(err){
            if(err) throw err;

        })
        socket.emit("update","saved successfully");
            console.log("saved successfully !");




    })
    socket.on('save',function(data){
        var entry = new User(data);
        entry.save(function(err){
            if(err) throw err;
            socket.emit("saved","saved successfully");
            console.log("saved successfully !");
        })
    })
})
```

Desktop-Client side (Firefox)

```jquery
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<form action="">
Username <input type="text" class="username"> <br>
Message <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" class="message"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="send" class="send">
</form>

<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
    var data = {};
    $("form").on("submit",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        var usr = $(".username").val();
        var message = $(".message").val();
        data["user"] = usr;
        data["message"] = message;
        socket.emit("data",data);
        console.log(data);
    });

</script>
```

Apparently, the

```js
socket.emit("update","saved successfully");
```

is not handled in swift. Anyway i'm afraid to not understand where to cath this event in my swift application without being required to start an event or re launch the iOs simulator.

Thanks for Help.